# How to set printing options as reverse order as default on 18.04

Tags: printing

When I go to printers, printing options, there isn't an option to set reverse order as default.

How to do it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. Open "Printers" Program.
2. Click "Additional Printer Settings..." to invoke advanced settings.
3. Select your printer, right click and click "Properties".

[image] →
[image]

4. On the left pane, select "Job Options".
5. Click "More" to display hidden options.
6. Set the "Output order" from Normal → Reverse.

[image]

7. Click apply then to save the configuration.

Comment: You should add that we have to enter first on Additional Printer Options, then I accept your answer

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand what you mean by  _enter first_, please clarify to me.

Comment: Before you get the window of the first picture you uploaded, there is an step you didnt mention. Because when you open printers application you should then click on “Additional printer option” to arrive to the first picture you uploaded.

Comment: @VitorAbella I assume you meant this https://i0.wp.com/websiteforstudents.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/11/ubuntu_printer_install.png ?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using CUPS, you want select "Printers" on the top menu bar, then select the printer you're interested in from the displayed list. Select the "Administration" button which reveals a pull-down menu (not Administration in the top menu bar). In the pull-down menu, select "Set Default Options." This reveals several option categories between two horizontal lines. Select "Printer Features Common." This reveals a new page of several features. Select the pull down menu next to "Orientation." From the pull down menu, select the option "Reverse Portrait" (or "Reverse Landscape" if that is your preference). Click on the button "Set Default Options." That's it. You can close CUPS or leave it open as you prefer.